# Remove and update users messages from group via telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to remove or edit users messages in group via telegram bot api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can**

- [edit you own messages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages).

You **can't**

- remove your own / other users messages
- edit other users messages